# transform from Firestore API to firebase rtdb api

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

recently im learning to create a event from a tutorial, but the original one is made in firestore, and Im trying to use firebase rtdb,

here is original code:

```
class FirebaseApi {
  static Future<String> createTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final docTodo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').doc();

    todo.id = docTodo.id;
    await docTodo.set(todo.toJson());

    return docTodo.id;
  }
}
```

here is code I created, sorry my basic knowledge is now good, Idk what should i return

```
class FirebaseApi {

  static Future<String> createTodo(Todo todo) async{

    final todoRefMessages = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('todo');
    
    final newTodo = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('todo').get().then((snapshot) async{
      final json = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);

      final newTodo = Todo(
        createdTime: Utils.toDateTime(json['createdTime']),
        title: json['title'],
        description: json['description'],
        id: json['id'],
        isDone: json['isDone'],
      );

      await todoRefMessages.set(newTodo.toJson());
      return newTodo;
    });

    todo.id= newTodo.id;//here got error, The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Todo>

    return newTodo.id;

  }
}
```

could you please let me know how to create same method but for firebase rtdb, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call to Firestore give you a reference to a new non-existing document in the `todo` collection:

```
final docTodo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').doc();
```

Is equivalent to this in the Realtime Database is:

```
final todoRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("todo").push();
```

---

Then to store the JSON to that document in Firestore you do:

```
await docTodo.set(todo.toJson());
```

The equivalent in the Realtime Database is:

```
await todoRef.set(todo.toJson());
```

---

If you have errors in other parts of your code, I recommend keeping the functionality of your `createTodo` method exactly the same between the Firestore and Realtime Database implementations.

For example, I assume that the `Todo todo` object is exactly the same between the implementations. If it isn't, the problem is less likely to be in the database API calls, but probably in the implementation of `Todo`.

Comment: dear Frank, thanks a lot for your help, here is still confusion for me, for firestore, it seems ok to get id directly(todo.id = docTodo.id), but I cant do the same work from your answer like this (todo.id = todoRef.id), which is the part im struggling, could you plz explain more, is it correct to write like this(todo.id = todoRef.key)？ thank you!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Firestore, as the `Todo` class is yours as far as I can tell. But you seem to have a scoping problem in the second snippet due to `FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('todo').get().then((snapshot) async{`. Since the first snippet doesn't read the document from Firestore, the second snippet also shouldn't be reading anything from Realtime Database. That's why I gave you a line-by-line translation in my answer, so that the `createTodo` implementation can be the same - with just the Firebase API calls being different.